# Auth0 fails to import ManagementClient on Azure

Tags: node.js, typescript, auth0, auth0-js

This works locally, but crashes on Azure App Service. I've tried every possible way of importing managementclient and it fails. I'm also raising a support issue with my account manager.

auth0-mgmt.ts

```
import { ManagementClient } from "auth0"

export async function userNickname(userId: string): Promise<string | null> {
  const m = new ManagementClient({
    domain: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL ?? "",
    clientId: process.env.AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
  })
  try {
    const user = await m.users.get({ id: userId, fields: "nickname" })
    return user.data?.nickname
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error getting user nickname:", error)
    return null
  }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
023-12-13T00:13:17.886814980Z import { ManagementClient } from "auth0"
2023-12-13T00:13:17.886823080Z          ^
2023-12-13T00:13:17.886827981Z
2023-12-13T00:13:17.886832481Z SyntaxError: The requested module 'auth0' does not provide an export named 'ManagementClient'
2023-12-13T00:13:17.886837181Z     at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:131:21)
2023-12-13T00:13:17.886841582Z     at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:213:5)
2023-12-13T00:13:17.886845982Z     at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
2023-12-13T00:13:17.886850682Z     at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
2023-12-13T00:13:17.886858183Z     at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:66:12)
2023-12-13T00:13:17.894145144Z
2023-12-13T00:13:17.894163946Z Node.js v20.9.0
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
...
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
...
  "dependencies": {
...
    "auth0": "^4.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, my Azure App Service box had an old file laying around from a really old deploy, called `auth0.ts`. Wow! Deleting it from `wwwroot` by sshing into the box fixed this issue.

Now to figure out why the `az webapp up` deploy command does *not* remove old files when it deploys! This is quite crazy -- does anyone know why it behaves this way?